# Flutter, WebView - rebuild with custom HTML

Tags: flutter, webview

I want to show some generated HTML in a [WebView](https://pub.dev/packages/webview_flutter) in my Flutter App.
The StatefulWidget which contains the WebView can change certain properties upon which the WebView would have to rebuild.

**TL;DR: How to supply custom HTML *without* `initialUrl`?**

Up to now I used the `initialUrl` propety of the WebView constructor to supply an URI with my HTML directly embedded:

```dart
WebView(
  initialUrl: Uri.dataFromString(myHtml, mimeType: 'text/html').toString(),
)
```

Now I realized, I must rebuild the WebView with different values when some states get set. (Namely a dropdown above the WebView). As the name tells, this URI is just initial.

So my question is: How can I update the HTML in the WebView? Is there maybe some way to reset the internal state of the WebView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess webview's api doesn't allow to do that, but you can use a workaround: just save the HTML to temp file and provide an URI to `WebView` using `initialUrl`. Here's the example:

```dart
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:webview_flutter/webview_flutter.dart';

class HomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() => _HomePageState();
}

class _HomePageState extends State<HomePage> {
  Uri uri;

  Future<void> _showHtml(String html) async {
    final tempDir = await getTemporaryDirectory();
    final path = join(tempDir.path, 'page.html');
    final tempFile = File(path);
    tempFile.writeAsStringSync(html);
    setState(() {
      uri = Uri(scheme: 'file', path: path);
    });
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _showHtml('<html>Test</html>');
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: uri != null ? WebView(
          initialUrl: uri.toString(),
        ) : Container()
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

You can also use `onWebViewCreated` callback to save webview's controller and use the controller later to load other using `loadUrl` method.